# ArcGIS 10.2.2: How to display attribute values using a representative number of symbols?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, symbology, mapping

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 Advanced. I want to produce a map where the value of attributes in each polygon is shown by a representative number of symbols in each polygon. I have used Quantities > Dot Density,  but this assigns the dots to randomised locations within the polygon and I want the symbols to be adjacent to each other as in the example picture attached. Preferably, I would like a solution which allows me to change the dot to a vector symbol of choice as well. I have searched through Stack Exchange and online, but haven't found a way to do this. Has anyone else figured out a way of doing this in ArcGIS? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [label expression](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm) with Python parser. Replace º with whatever character you want to use:

```
def FindLabel ([X]):
  s = int([X])
  label = ''.join(['º' for i in range(s)])
  return label
```

[image]

To get a line break every fifth charachter try:

```
def FindLabel ( [X]  ):
  s = int([X])
  label = ['●' for i in range(s)]
  i = 5
  while i < len(label):
    label.insert(i, "\r\n")
    i += 6
  return ''.join(label)
```

[image]